# Selenium WebDriver - compile HTML string

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Selenium `WebDriver` to compile html `String`, the only examples i found are for opening files like :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/jgong/Desktop/a.html");
```

I need:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(htmlString);
```

and then use the `getPageSource()` method, is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *compile html String*? this is very unclear.

Comment: Compile the js + html like the browser does.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas Selenium is a free (open source) automated testing suite for web applications across different browsers and platforms. Selenium cannot compile `HTML` files. When you mention `driver.get("file:///C:/Users/jgong/Desktop/a.html");` Selenium will open the `a.html` page through the browser of your choice. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `data` URI scheme to load some HTML with Selenium:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + htmlString);
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. All the html code was put in the address bar and driver.find_element was not returning anything.

Comment: It has serious limitations. It is not able to parse inline styles. If you used any inline style (that contains color), it will break and stop parsing the remainder of the page.